# How to remove, and not just hide, a question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Is there a way to definitively remove a question that I have, such that it no longer exists in any form on the site, and not just hide it from most users?

Comment: You mean you don't want to see the questions in the list, or you want them to actually not exist on the site, in any form?

Comment: if i can know both of them this will be good @Servy

Comment: You should be asking one question per question.

Comment: ok @Servy can you answer the second one **want them to actually not exist on the site, in any form?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general, no.  The only way that this would happen is if the person that provided the content included sensitive information such as passwords or personal data. In that case, moderators and staff can redact the information out of the post like it never existed (but it would not wipe the post completely).

Outside of that exception, posts are never *actually* deleted, even if the author would wish that it be deleted.  It is simply hidden from users, other than the author(s), that don't have the privilege to see deleted posts.

Comment: thank you @Servy this can gives me an idea

Comment: so for that when you remove a question or an answer the number of questions or answers not change?

Comment: @L.Y What number?  The number of questions/answer in SE's database?  No, it would stay the same.  The number of questions/answers shown on your public profile?  Sure, they list *undeleted* posts, and are therefore affected by a post being deleted.

Comment: @L.Y your "that gives me an idea" comment worries me.

Answer (score 1):

If no one commented or answer your question and no more than 5 minutes past from posting, you can edit the body and title of the question with a placeholder, e.g. dot symbols. This edit will not in the revision list, so nobody (perhaps even a mod) can see about what your question was anymore.